# Webpack 5.3.1 TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ionic2, webpack-5

I am trying to overwrite the webpack.config.js for an IONIC project. When I include webpack to the webpack.config.js it gives be below Error.

Webpack version : 5.1.3

```
**webpack.config.js**
var webpack = require('webpack');
```

```
**ERROR :**
TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function
    at mergeExports (/Users/XXXX/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:48:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/XXXX/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:75:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Comment: I believe you should update your `nodejs`

Comment: Its a big project and can't update the nodejs as its failing on the latest Node so have to fix them 1st. I am on Node 6.14.x

Comment: then search for polyfills. in this case you need `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` polyfill. maybe more will be required. I would still try to update nodejs in your place

Comment: Currently I downgrade webpack version to 3.x to make it work as a workaround.

Comment: polyfills imo is a better option. if other libs expect webpack5 some of their functionalities may fail. with polyfills everything should work just fine